# Different layouts selected by android studio emulator and real android device Mate 9

Tags: android, layout, android-resources

Why different layouts are selected by android studio emulator and real android device mate 9?

Huawei Mate 9 is 1080 x 1920 px device with a 5.99 inch display (its an xhdpi type device) and Samsung galaxy S9 is 1080 x 2220 px device with 5.8 inch display (its an xxhdpi device).

Now, my problem is that I do have a separate xxhdpi layout for Samsung S9 device and xhdpi layout for Mate 9 device. The android studio emulator is selecting the correct layouts for corresponding devices but real Mate 9 device is selecting xxhdpi layout at runtime. This is resulting in improper alignment of components in my app. Why this problem is arising and what is its solution?
Someone here please help me out.
Thanks

Comment: Probably `real Mate 9` is `xxhdpi ` What is the DPI/PPI

Comment: its 373 ppi on mate 9

Comment: and 570 ppi on s9